# jupyter notebookのnbextensionsのhinterlandの使い方

Tags: python3, jupyter-notebook

入力補完を行いたく、掲記のとおり、nbextensionsをインストールし、hinterlandを有効にしました。

結果、候補はいくつか表示されるようになったのですが、その中からどのように選択すればよいのかわかりません。↓では選択できず、どのキーを押せば選択できるのかご教示賜れればと存じます。

Comment: 今手元のanaconda (201907)に `conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`で入れてhinterlandを有効化して、OS XのChromeで確認してみましたがカーソルキー（↓）でリスト内移動してEnterで反映できました。OS、ブラウザなどの環境も書いた方がいいと思います。あとは日本語入力などにキー入力が奪われていないかも確認してみてください（私の環境は日本語入力でもカーソルで移動はできてましたが別環境ではわからないので）。

Comment: 確かに環境について記載を忘れておりました。すみません。OSはWindows10、ブラウザはEdgeです。なお、ご案内に従い、Chromeにしてみたら普通につかえました。